# Asio sync-read random-access with exceptions, how many bytes were read?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

How can we know how many bytes were read when calling a synchronous read operation on a random-access device and it throws an exception, for example `random_access_file` ?

Is this not supported, and to know how many bytes were read, one is supposed to take the `boost::system::error_code ec` overload?

```
error_code ec;
size_t s = a.read_some_at(offset, buffers, ec);
offset += s; // need to be done before unwinding
if (ec) throw system_error(ec);
return s;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. Take the `ec` overload. This has been the case for partial-success operations in Asio.

Slightly longer (irrelevant) answer: when using e.g. c++20 coroutines you can make the error-code and byte-count be returned [as a tuple](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/token_adapters.html#boost_asio.overview.composition.token_adapters.as_tuple), which you might find more convenient:

```
auto [ec, s] = a.async_read_some_at(offset, buffers, asio::as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable)));
```

Pet peeve: `as_tuple` doesn't at current (last checked 1.80.0) appear to work well with `asio::use_future` :(

Comment: I prefer to _almost always_ take the `ec` overload, you can always throw an exception in your application layer if you need to.  Seldom does boost have *all* of the relevant details when throwing an exception to let you properly diagnose an issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'm writing a stream-like-class that simply wraps a random-access-file and passing it an offset, and has an offset integer in it that increments whenever read_some / async_read_some is called on it. That's why  I need to know how many bytes were read. Still need to figure out how I get the number of read/written bytes in the async_{read,write}_some case. Seems like I need to wrap the token and intercept the "bytes_read" integer. I'm still investivating how to properly do that without losing anything like associated executor etc. Is this the "Completion Token Adapters" stuff?

Comment: The goal is that then I can use boost::buffered_stream with the random access file, when reading contiguous records from the file.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb in general using async completion exposes both the error code and the bytes transferred just fine (e.g using a handler `void(error_code, size_t)` or indeed using `as_tuple(use_awaitable)`. The latter is indeed described under Completion Token Adaptors. As mentioned it doesn't play well with `use_future`, but that is not asynchronous anyways.

Comment: Thanks! I made my own completion token adapter that takes the size and adds it to a size reference. It works with any kind of completion token as a wrapper.